# Custominze transition in tailwaindcss

Tags: css, sass, css-transitions, tailwind-css

i am working on a dashboard and recently adam (tailwindcss) made a scren cast on kanban of trello like dashboard. I liked it and was trying to implement it. the issue i am at is related to the transition effects used by him in screen cast. they are not yet in tailwindcss but in future they will be. i did a bit of digging and was able to implement it. But the issue is as follow.

```css
.translate-x-full {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
          transform: translateX(100%);
}

.-translate-x-full {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
          transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.translate-x-0 {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
          transform: translateX(0);
}
```

this is the css code to make transition it works well be i only have issue in desktop mode where `.-translate-x-full` this is implemented even if i use `lg:translate-x-0'.
This might be due as tailwindcss don't have transition as of yet. so my question is, how can i make`lg:translate-x-0' work and over write, `.-translate-x-full` effect.

below is the code in aside menu:

```php
<div 
:class="sideBarOpen ? 'translate-x-0 ease-out transition-medium': '-translate-x-full ease-in transition-medium'"
class="aside fixed z-30 inset-y-0 left-0 w-64 px-8 py-4 bg-gray-100 border-r border overflow-auto lg:translate-x-0 lg:static lg:inset-auto"
>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found a solution with was something i need.

to make my custom css responsive i just had to put it inside a `responsive` wrapper like below:

```
@responsive {

.translate-x-full {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
          transform: translateX(100%);
}

.-translate-x-full {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
          transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.translate-x-0 {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
          transform: translateX(0);
}


}
```

and it created all the required classes. plus normally, class with `-` as start like `.-class-name` won't complite into normall css for some unknown reason. but here that to is working and solved lot's of issue.